# Trying to hide a button on a specific WordPress Page ID

Tags: css

I am trying to hide this button:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://example.org/about/';">About Me</button>
```

The entire HTML (for that specific section) is (including the title):

```
<aside id="secondary" class="widget-area">
        <div class="about-wrapper">
        <h2 class="widget-title">About Me</h2>
                <p class="about-copy"> text </p>
        </div>
</aside>
```

The Page ID is 52, I checked in the code and saw this:

```
<body class="page-template-default page page-id-52 no-sidebar">
```

The issue is that there isn't a CSS class....maybe I should add one - or - is there another way to hide this JavaScript button per Page ID in WordPress?

Comment: Did you check if `page-id-52` class is actually present?

Comment: Hi @Himad yes I did and have updated question

Comment: If you use Chrome, can you check with the developer tools if the CSS is being applied?

Comment: Perhaps your rule does work, but there's a more specific rule that says otherwise? Is this just a CSS question? If so you might get more eyes on this if you asked on stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry @Himad my question was worded all wrong. The issue is the button not the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if you want to remove/hide only the button can do this:
1 - if you have a specific class that hide a element
//$class = "youre class";

```
 <button class="<?php if(is_page($page_id)){ echo $class } ?>" 
 onclick="window.location.href='https://example.org/about/';">About Me</button>
```

2 - inline style

```
 <button  <?php if(is_page($page_id)){ echo "style="display: none"; } ?>" 
 onclick="window.location.href='https://example.org/about/';">About Me</button>
```